# setTimeout как найти определенную функцию в стеке?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, стек

Возможно ли как-то посмотреть какие функции есть в стеке для вызова, которые были добавлены в стек при помощи функции setTimeout?

То есть, можно ли как-то проверить будет ли та или иная функция вызвана через n времени при помощи механизма setTimeout?

Comment: Переопределить setTimeout?

Comment: такого механизма нет.

Comment: разве что создать кастомный стек, тем более однопоточность JS к этому распологает